# Подзапрос в decode(...)

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Добрый день.
Есть строка селекта

```
select

count(decode(:g_control_type, not null, ct.day_jan, ... )

from TABLE_1 ct
```

Проблема в том, что вместо ... в конструкции decode мне нужно поместить условие "все значения ct.day_jan таблицы TABLE_1 ct где столбец ct.control_type in (1 ... нужные мне значения)"

Т.е. логически это должно звучать так:
"количество значений столбца ct.day_jan, но в случае, если бинд-переменная g_control_type = Null, то только значения ct.day_jan, находящиеся в нужном диапазоне."

Существует вариант поместить подобный подзапрос в указанное место в decode? Если нет, как можно построить подзапрос, чтобы он возвращал логически правильный результат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT` считает количество ненулевых значений переданного в него выражения.

Соответственно, чтобы подсчитать нужные значения требуется вместо ненужных возвращать `NULL`.

В запросе ниже использовал `CASE` вместо `DECODE` чтобы явно показать обработку `NULL`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN :g_control_type is null THEN
            --если NULL считаем диапазон 
            CASE WHEN ct.control_type in (/*диапазон*/) THEN
                ct.day_jan
            ELSE 
                null
            END
        ELSE
            ct.day_jan
        END
    )
FROM table_1 ct
```

Верхний `CASE` можно переписать как `DECODE`, только нужно учесть что условия `not null` не бывает и разобраться с типами полей/переменных.

По ситуации, для ясности можно поместить переменную привязки в условие напрямую:

```
CASE WHEN :g_control_type is null AND ct.control_type IN ...
```

либо поменять местами обработку переменной и COUNT:

```
CASE WHEN :g_control_type is null THEN
    COUNT(--один подсчет
ELSE
    COUNT(--другой подсчет
END
```

Comment: Воспользовался вашим вариантом - то, что было необходимо. Благодарю!

Comment: @n0n4m3 Пожалуйста! Я дал ответ на вопрос «как написать нужный COUNT» и полагал, что в запросе могут быть другие условия и/или выбираемые значения. Если их нет, то имеет смысл перенести условия  в WHERE как советует MaxU

Comment: Да, ответ MaxU подходит, но в моем случае имеется ряд вложенных запросов и условий, потому здесь подошел ваш вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать так (если я правильно понял условия):

```
select count(ct.day_jan)
from table_1
where :g_control_type is NOT NULL OR ct.control_type in (/*1 ... нужные мне значения*/);
```